# How to use variable with awk when being read from a file

Tags: bash, variables, awk

I have a file with the following entries:

```
foop07_bar2_20190423152612.zip
foop07_bar1_20190423153115.zip
foop08_bar2_20190423152612.zip
foop08_bar1_20190423153115.zip
```

where

```
foop0* = host
bar* = fp
```

I would like to read the file and create 3 variables, the whole file name, host and fp (which stands for file_path_differentiator).

I am using read to take the first line and get my whole file name variable, I though I could then feed this into awk to grab the next two variables, however the first method of variable insertion creates an error and the second gives me all the variables.

I would like to loop each line, as I wish to use these variables to ssh to the host and grab the file

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r FILE
do
    echo ${FILE}
    host=`awk 'BEGIN { FS = "_" } ; { print $1 }'<<<<"$FILE"`
    echo ${host}
    path=`awk -v var="${FILE}" 'BEGIN { FS = "_" } ; { print $2 }'`
    echo ${path}
done <zips_not_received.csv
```

Expected Result

```
foop07_bar2_20190423152612.zip 
foop07
bar2
foop07_bar1_20190423153115.zip
foop07
bar1
```

Actual Result

```
foop07_bar2_20190423152612.zip
/ : No such file or directoryfoop07_bar2_20190423152612.zip

bar2 bar1 bar2 bar1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this alone with `bash`, without using any external tool.

```
while read -r file; do
    [[ $file =~ (.*)_(.*)_.*\.zip ]] || { echo "invalid file name"; exit 1; }
    host="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    path="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    echo "$file"
    echo "$host"
    echo "$path"
done < zips_not_received.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

typical...

Managed to work a solution after posting...

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r FILE
do
 echo ${FILE}
 host=`echo "$FILE" | awk -F"_" '{print $1}'`
 echo $host
 path=`echo "$FILE" | awk -F"_" '{print $2}'`
 echo ${path}
done <zips_not_received.csv
```

not sure on the elegance or its correctness as i am using echo to create variable...but i have it working..

Comment: You can also do `while IFS=_ read -r host path rest; do echo "${host}_${path}_${rest}"; echo "$host"; echo "$path"; done <file`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no space or _ in your "file name" that are part of the host or path

just separate line before with sed, awk, ... if using default space separator (or use _ as argument separator in batch). I add the remove of empty line value as basic security seeing your sample.

```
sed 's/_/ /g;/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/d' zips_not_received.csv \
 | while read host path Ignored
    do
      echo "${host}"
      echo "${path}"
    done
```

Comment: As mentioned, `while IFS=_ read host path Ignored` may also work for you.